# form validation, hundreds of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I'm building a checkbox form with well over 200 questions (don't ask lol), and I don't want the user to be able to go to the results page without at LEAST having one checkbox checked. 
Problem is, writing something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['q1']) || isset($_POST['q2']) || isset($_POST['q3'])..............)
```

for hundreds of questions is going to be... long. Is there any way to make it shorter?

the code snippet:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q1" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q2" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q3" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q4" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q5" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q6" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 6<br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" class="button" value="Submit" /> 
</form>

 <?php 
include 'defaults.php';
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
   if(isset($_POST['q1'])) {$_SESSION['q1v'] = 1;};
   if(isset($_POST['q2'])) {$_SESSION['q2v'] = 1;};
   if(isset($_POST['q3'])) {$_SESSION['q3v'] = 1;};
   if(isset($_POST['q4'])) {$_SESSION['q4v'] = 1;};
   if(isset($_POST['q5'])) {$_SESSION['q5v'] = 1;};
   if(isset($_POST['q6'])) {$_SESSION['q6v'] = 1;};

   header('Location: results.php');

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make them an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q[1]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q[2]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 2<br>
etc...
```

Then to check that at least one is checked (if none are checked then the `q` array will not exist):

```
if(isset($_POST['q']))
```

And simply this for the session vars:

```
$_SESSION['q'] = $_POST['q'];
```

So maybe:

```
if(isset($_POST['q'])) {
    $_SESSION['q'] = $_POST['q'];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. It recognizes that an array was created, however it doesn't seem to assign anything inside the array. If I do    `if(isset($_POST['q'])) {
    $_SESSION['q'] = $_POST['q'];
 echo count($q);` it gives me an undefined variable error

Comment: That's because you didn't assign anything to `$q`.  If you want an array `$q` you would need `$q = $_POST['q'];`

Comment: ah, right. I'm new to all this. Thanks again, it works.

Comment: one more question... how the hell do I echo out an item from an array inside a session? edit: nvm I got it

Answer (score 1):

If you make all the checkboxes have a name like: name="myCheckBoxes[]" then you can process the post value like an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q[]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q[]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q[]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q[]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q[]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q[]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 6<br>

 <?php 
include 'defaults.php';
if(isset($_POST['q'])) {
  $questions=$_POST['q'];   <-- $questions is an array and easier to work with

   header('Location: results.php');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a naming convention you could just do this in a loop:

```
$checkbox_count = 200;
$prefix = 'q';

for($i = 1; $i <= $checkbox_count; $i++){
   $key = sprintf("%s%u", $prefix, $i);
   if(isset($_POST[$key])){
      $_SESSION[$key.'v'] = 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can make an array like bellow

`<input type="checkbox" name="myarray[]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="myarray[]" onclick="KeepCount()" value="1">Question 2<br>`

then take the value as an array like bellow

$myarray = $_POST['myarray'];`

then check them with php foreach, are they empty

```
 foreach($myarray as $key=>$value){
  if(!isset($value)){
  $error_status = true}
```

if status is true, you can redirect him/her in any page like bellow

```
 if($error_status==true){
  header('location: anypage.php');
  }
  else{
  header('location:results.php');
  }
```